# Text Encoding UTF-8 character set?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using UTF-8 text encoding, I want to that in this encoding method which type of characters will come? I am using

```
encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp)
Dim encodedData As String = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte)
```

Any one can tell me about this? I want to ignore characters like `$`, `#`, `@` and similar symbols because I am using this encoding string in url.
dear friends i don't want to use this Http Utility Encoding method, can you tell me about text encoding utf-8 getbytes method? 
Anything helpful will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you try

`Server.UrlEnCode(encodedData)` or

`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(encodedData)` or

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodedData)`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to exclude this characters from url, simply replace it: `encodedData.Replace("$","").Replace("#","").Replace("@","")`

Comment: when i replace those symbols with empty string then how can i decode them?

Comment: @AqEeL encodedData = encodedData.Replace("$","").Replace("#","").Replace("@",""); Then HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedData)

Comment: dear i don't want to use this method can you tell me about text encoding utf-8 getbytes method?

Comment: No, I don't know how to replace byte by byte or how to remove the bytes

Comment: Leon is there a way to restrict this encoding that gets byte so there will be only that output which we require? well thanks for your time

Comment: @AqEeL I can't understand you last comment. As I know, Encoding.GetBytes no let you any way to exclude or make an output, it as the others encoding, only transform string to an array of bytes. I supose, if you know the byte value of the chars you want to ignore or exclude you can search what are the positions and remove it

Comment: but it would not a better approach to resolve this issue. I want to restrict that encoding to not generate any special characters, my input will be integer only i am using this method and its generating = symbol and i handled this. but if it will generate anything anything else than i want to ignore that symbol.

Comment: They aren't special symbols, are a few characters included in this and others encodings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16650/discussion-between-aqeel-and-alberto-leon)